# Ошибка при логгировании Log4J

Tags: java, log4j

Здравствуйте! Написал тестовый класс

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;


import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


public class TestGreeting {
    private Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    private ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("greeting",   defaultLocale);
    private String comparableString = "";
    private String greeting = "";

@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman = new GreetingWatcher();

@Test
public void testMorningGreeting() {
    greeting = rb.getString("my.morning");
    comparableString = Greeting.getGreeting("morning");
    assertTrue(comparableString.equals(greeting));
}

@Test
public void testDayGreeting() {
    greeting = rb.getString("my.day");
    comparableString = Greeting.getGreeting("day");
    assertTrue(comparableString.equals(greeting));
}

@Test
public void testEveningGreeting() {
    greeting = rb.getString("my.evening");
    comparableString = Greeting.getGreeting("evening");
    assertTrue(comparableString.equals(greeting));
}

@Test
public void testNightGreeting() {
    greeting = rb.getString("my.night");
    comparableString = Greeting.getGreeting("night");
    assertTrue(comparableString.equals(greeting));
    }
}
```

Запускаю тестовый класс и выдает такую ошибку, как бы я не менял кофигурационный файл (находится в java/test/resources):

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

Все необходимые библиотеки присутствуют. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Не `java/test/resources`, а `src/test/resources`. Непонятно какое отношение ваш юнит-тест вообще имеет к конфигурации логгера...

Comment: Думал, может в этом причина. Проблема решилась сама собой, IntelliJ докачала нужные либы